# Actionscript 3 Control Timeline after Duration of no input from user

Tags: actionscript-3

can anyone help me with this. I know its something very basic, but I just cant work it out.

What I need is for the timeline gotoandstop at frame 1 after 15 seconds of inactivity.

Basically this is for a directory board so if no one is using it, it will return back to the home screen after a period of inactivity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

its possible to simulate it so:

```
class test extends MovieClip{
    public var myTimer:Number;
    public var input:TextField;

    function test(){
       myTimer=0;
       input=new TextField();
       this.addChild(input);
       this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,timer);
       input.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, input_from_user);
    }

    function timer(ev){
      myTimer +=(1/25);//if the frame rate is 25 frame per sconde
      if(myTimer ==15){
         this.gotoAndStop(1);
         this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,timer);   
      }
    }

    function input_from_user(ev){
        myTimer =0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but its not working I get these errors.
Main, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 4 1135: Syntax error: function is not a valid type.
Main, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 4 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before test.
Main, Layer 'Actions', Frame 4 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.

Comment: 3rd line, write `public var input:TextField;`

Comment: Thanks so much, appreciate it. But just one more error. I think its because the actionscript is nested in a movie object.     Symbol 'Wayfinder', Layer 'Actions', Frame 4, Line 1 1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before leftparen.

Comment: @MarkR what is your line 1 on frame 4? Also I think that class name should be capital `Test` not written as `test`...

Comment: class test extends MovieClip{ is line 1.. I tried putting a capital T, but nothing happened. I still keep getting this error Symbol 'Wayfinder', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 1 1131: Classes must not be nested.

Comment: Dear Mark R Create a test.as file and set your main document class to test and i was just giving you the idea then i didn't focused on details because you didn't clarify what exactly you mean by user input but if your wanting to use this example i have presumed you meant 'text input'. i have edited it for you now it may work

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is use a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) object.  Then, whenever the user moves the mouse or clicks or presses a key, reset that timer back to 15 seconds.

On your frame 1, make a timer object:

```
//create the timer object var
var resetTimer:Timer;

//if it doesn't exist yet, create a new timer object and assign it to that var
if(!resetTimer){
    resetTimer = new Timer(15000,1); //tick 1 time with a delay of 15 
    //listen for the TIMER event (fires when the delay is up)
    resetTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, reset);seconds
}else{
    resetTimer.reset(); //if it did previously exist, stop/reset it (for when you revisit frame 1)
}

//go back to the first frame if the timer fires
function reset(e:Event = null):void {
    resetTimer.reset(); //reset the timer
    gotoAndStop(1);  //go to frame 1
}


//LISTEN for various user input type events on stage (globally)
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, userInput);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, userInput);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, userInput);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, userInput);

//if there was user input, reset the timer and start it again
function userInput(e:Event = null):void {
    resetTimer.reset();
    resetTimer.start();
}
```

The only thing left to do is, when you leave frame 1 and want the timeout to be applicable call `resetTimer.start()`.  Presumably that would be on frame 2.